# Can't keep notification sound playing after notification drawer is opened

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-alarms, android-notification-bar

I'm trying to make an alarm app, and I'm really close, but I want the alarm sound to keep playing until the user has manually disabled it via my app (puzzle to turn off alarm type idea).  The problem Im having now is that the sound plays up until I pull down the notification drawer, then it stops.
Here is the relevant code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(alarm.getLabel());
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(alarm.getMessage());
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    if(alarm.getVibrate()) {
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notificationManager.notify(2, notification);
```

I have tried messing around with the flags, but nothing seems to keep it playing...
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Anyone know anything about this...?

Comment: Need this ans too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.  Had to use a background Service to play the ringtone rather than the notification manager.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you share a code snippet of what you did?